# Php PDO issues translating from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay, I'm really struggling to get to grasps with PDO, even after 2 days of trying to convert everything.

I'm now at the stage of creating an array for the `$user_data['???']` And here's what I've got.

```
if (logged_in() === true) {
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'active', 'coins');
    $user_id = $user_data['id'];
    if (user_active($user_data['username'] === false) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

So that's my way of getting the data for `$user_data['???']` The functions to go with it are..

```
function user_data($user_id){
    $data = array(); 
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = //mysql_fetch_assoc(//mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));

        return $data;
    }
}

function user_active($username) { 
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = //mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1");
    return (//mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to convert this into PDO, can anyone give me any help?

Also, after I do convert it to PDO. Would it be as simple for to say welcome the user with a simple message of `Welcome <?php $user_data['username'] ?>, Hope you enjoy your stay!` or would I need to use a completely different method now?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: **Read answers to your other questions.** It will save you A LOT of hair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So by the looks of the example code I get the impression that you're migrating from the deprecated mysql extension over to PDO.

Something the mysql extension does that may be tripping you up is that if you don't specify the mysql link resource to `mysql_query` it uses the lastly created link resource that was created by `mysql_connect`. Once you move to using PDO you're going to have to have the PDO connection available in the `user_data` and `user_active` functions. The simplest approach would be to create a PDO connection in each function, it's terribly repetitive and not a good solution at all, but it works.

There are also some issues with [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) vulnerabilities in the code. Aside from that you could write the functions like this:

```
<?php

function user_data($user_id){
  $data = array(); 
  $user_id = (int)$user_id;

  $func_num_args = func_num_args();
  $func_get_args = func_get_args();

  if ($func_num_args > 1) {
    unset($func_get_args[0]);

    // connect to the DB
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=<your_db_name>;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = '<your_db_user>';
    $password = '<your_db_user_password>';
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    // request the data
    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
    $sql = sprintf('select %s from users where user_id = ? limit 1', $fields);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($userid));
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $data;
  }
}

function user_active($username) { 
  $username = sanitize($username);

  // connect to the DB
  $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=<your_db_name>;host=127.0.0.1';
  $user = '<your_db_user>';
  $password = '<your_db_user_password>';
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

  $sql = 'select count(user_id) from users where username = ? and active';
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(array($username));

  return $stmt->fetchColumn() == 1;      

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to work with the connection. PDO is OO:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=somedb",'root');
```

Then you get the rows:

```
$rows = $db->query('select name from People');
```

Your function should be something like:

```
function user_data($user_id,$db){
    $data = array(); 
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = $db->query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");

        return $data;
    }
}



function user_active($username,$db) { 
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $data = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) qtd FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1");
    return ($data['qtd'] == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Where $db is a PDO instance with a valid connection. So, if we have an script to call the functions, it should be like this:

```
<?php
  import "file_where_functions_are_defined.php";
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=somedb",'root');
  $user_data = user_data(1,$db);
?>
```

Comment: No password? also, Why start a new PDO connection from inside every function?

Comment: It is just to answer your question. You can create a variable to use it in both functions. It should be better if you encapsulate it within a class and using singleton to keep one connection only. Regarding the password, it depends how your server is configured. My local machine don not need password. YOu need to adapt it to your world.

Comment: Regardless, you shouldn't be giving an example for multiple connection strings. If the OP would use this, as is and making slight changes but keeping your base structure.. Forever time he changes site/database.. He'll get alot of unwanted errors with mismatching passwords... Access the `$db` variable inside the function by using `global`

Comment: @JoseAreas You ARE responsible for the code you're giving away. Every answer is expected to serve MANY people, who come across in the future. Writing bad code means all these people to share this bad practice. So, "It is just to answer" is not an excuse. Either give a correct answer or don't write it at all.

Comment: A somewhat funny fact: in their previous answer the OP *already* used the very DI approach, even a type-hinted one. But for some reason not in this one.

Comment: Sorry guys. I was not thinking in create an entire program to answer the question. I just create some pieces of code to help the asker to move forward. I couldn't give him/her in one answer all the concepts he/she should be aware when writing code. This is only one small stuck and he/she needs a little push. I believe the little push was given by my answer. From now on, common sense and a lot of study must be used to move forward. Even though, the asker still will need other little pushes. Not complete programs. Small pushes to help him/her to move forward.That is how we can help.

Comment: I really do not believe that no answer could be better. Even to who will see the answer later will get help if the doubt is the same. Of course, it is just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jose, it's given me the "push" required. The connection I use is from a different file location, included in my init.php which is included when I need it. But the answer you've given me has made it clear how to get the result required from the problem I had. Thank you.