# PDO user_data function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So in my init.php file it checks to see if the user is logged in, that requires a function called `user_data($username)`

Here's what they contain.

init.php

```
if (logged_in() === true) {
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'coins', 'host', 'bets', 'online', 'multi');
    $user_id = $user_data['user_id'];   
    if (user_active($user_data['username']) === false) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

The function `user_data()` is

```
function user_data($user_id){
$data = array();
$user_id = (int)$user_id;

$func_num_args = func_num_args();
$func_get_args = func_get_args();

if ($func_num_args > 1) {
    unset($func_get_args[0]);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
    $sql = sprintf('SELECT `%s` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1', $fields);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($user_id));
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $data;
}
}
```

I get the error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object` is this because I'm not calling the function with `$db` or is my function just incorrect?

Comment: `$dbh` isn't in scope in `user_data()`

Comment: There's only one `$dbh` variable in all this code, and it's never being *declared* anywhere; much less within the scope of the function.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473791/php-pdo-issues-translating-from-mysql

Comment: And *somewhat* of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455378/pdo-with-mysql-not-working-in-email-activation where the OP had the code to pass the connection into function already, but lost it somewhere in the process :)

Comment: Thanks again detective common sense ;) I'm a huge beginner with all of this, and appreciate you letting me know every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't connected to the database. You should have a PDO database connection inside the user_data function, or global, or pass it in.

Comment: The connection is there, it's included outside of the function from the init.php

Comment: In that case just add "global $dbh" right after declaring the function. Functions don't have access to global resources unless you expressly mark them as global..